# Font extensions not working when creating a report

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a report that uses Greek characters and I'm having trouble displaying the Greek characters in the generated report. At first I was having the issue where the font wasn't available to the JVM. Now I have fixed this issue. I'm not getting any errors but the generated report still isn't showing the Greek characters.

I've set the font to be embedded in the PDF and selected the encoding to be Identity-H, I also tried using CP1253 (Greek) as PDF encoding but I'm getting the same results. In the report that Jaspersoft Studio is creating everything works fine. I can see the characters in the PDF that is being generated and the correct fonts are loaded when I check the PDF with Acrobat reader. My only problem is that when I create the PDF through my Java project the Greek characters are missing and I'm not getting any error messages or something that would hint at an error.

I've also exported the .jar file with the fonts and after building the maven project the .jar file is located in the /target/projectFolder/WEB-INF/lib directory.

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing? I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 6.2

Comment: See [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/adding-fonts-embedding-pdf), [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension), and [here for JasperServer](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/working-font-extensions).

Comment: I've followed all of these things and I can't make it work.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what you're missing because nobody was there to watch what you've done. Also, the question requires error messages and screen shots at the very least. Meanwhile, see [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_fonts.htm) for more examples and tutorials.